# Can show the right intent in luis.ai

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a problem with my luis.ai agent.
I created an intent , and i trained with some utterance. My problem consist that my utterance has a score 0.99 .

When i type this utterance in my bot ( an other utterance of this intent with score > 0.7)  ...the result was different .

For example :

Intent : mobile

Utterance : mobile application  . Predicted Intent : 0.9

Message : "xxxxxxxxx"

When i start conversation with my bot and type : mobile application , or what is mobile application . My bot turn another response ( from another intent): "yyyyyyyyyyy"

Do you have any idea how to resolve , maybe with my code ?

My code :

```
     using System.Net;
     using System.Net.Http;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.Web.Http;
     using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
     using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

     namespace FirstBotApplication
    {
    //[BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new AllTheBot());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
  }
 }
  `
```

Luis.cs

```
    `using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
     using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
     using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
     using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.IO;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.Web;


     namespace FirstBotApplication
      {
  //  [LuisModel("Please Enter Your LUIS Model ID", "Please Enter Your LUIS 
    Subscription Key")]

   [Serializable]
      [LuisModel("zzzzz", "zzzzzzzyyyy")]


    public class AllTheBot : LuisDialog<object>
     {
    // internal static string results;
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string message = $"Sorry, I did not understand '{result.Query}'. 
            Please reformulate your question";

        await context.PostAsync(message);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);

}

    [LuisIntent("grettings")]
    [LuisIntent("intentfr")]
    public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, 
      IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {

            await context.PostAsync("Welcome  ");

            context.Wait(MessageReceived);

    }

    [LuisIntent("test")]
    public async Task test(IDialogContext context, 
       IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Do you want to test our bot ? We suggest to 
     type : hi or who are you, help etc..");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }`

   [LuisIntent("Mobile")]
    public async Task mobile(IDialogContext context, 
   IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {

            await context.PostAsync(" xxxxxxx");


            context.Wait(MessageReceived);

    }}
```

Comment: where is the intent "mobile" in your code?

Comment: i will update my code with this intent ..is colled mobot

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following, in the code intent mobile is printing yyyyyy so the output you are seeing the expected. You won't get xxxxxx

Comment: sorry for this confuse moment...i want to print xxxxx ...but in fact my bot print a text from other intent

Comment: It sounds you need more training. Have you republished the luis app after retraining it?

Comment: yes i have done this( training and publish )...in the console of luis.ai when i time the utterance i take the right intent...bot not in my bot.

Comment: you are using the same Luis app in the bot, right? The code looks good. Maybe you can import your LUIS app, host the json somewhere to take a look to it

Comment: i'm using the same Luis app...the rare thing is that this happen only with one intent ( and all utterance of it ) ..not with other intent...when i type a utterance of this intent...i receive a different message ..not the message that i have program for this intent

Comment: can you put a few breakpoints to understand to what intent is arriving instead?

Comment: it is possible to do smth inside code like : if result=="mobile" { do xxx } ...how can i express in code

Comment: put breakpoints in your intent methods please and see where the message arrives

Comment: Are you perhaps using a different version of your Luis App?

Comment: are you sure you dont have any other intent on luis app with the same utterance